# Lyapunon candidate function to derive parameters estimation law

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, adaptive-control

I have a system and a reference model represented in state space in the following form:

\begin{gather}
\dot{x} = Ax+Bu \\\
u = \hat{K}(t)x+\hat{k}_r(t)r \\\
\\
A_m = A+BK \\\
Bk_r = B_m \\\
K,k_r : \text{desired controller  gains} \\ 
\dot{x}_m = A_mx_m+B_rr \ \text{Reference Model}
\end{gather}

where my goal is to design a direct (controller gains are updated directly) model reference adaptive controller for the system $x$ to track the reference model $x_m$ when there is bounded $r(t)$ signal as reference input. By defining the error terms to be: 
\begin{align}
e &= x_m - x \\ 
\tilde{K}(t)&=\hat{K}(t)-K \\
\tilde{K}_r(t)&=\hat{K}_r(t)-K_r
\end{align}
I have derived the system tracking error:

$$\dot{e} = A_me-B\tilde{K}(t)x-B\tilde{k}_r(t)r$$
What I want to do is derive update laws for the time changing controller parameters $\hat{K}$, $\hat{k}_r$. In order to do so I follow the Lyapunov procedure by defining a Lyapunov candidate function,computing its derivative and then trying to prove that the derivative is at least negative semi-definite. I chose the following Lyapunov candidate function:

$$V = e^TPe+|b|(\tilde{K}Γ^{-1}\tilde{K}^T+γ_r^{-1}\tilde{k}_r^2) $$

where $P$ is a positive definite matrix computed from the Lyapunov equation $A_m^TP+PA_m=-Q$ since $A_m$ is defined to be Hurwitz, $B=[0 \ \ b]^T$(sign of $b$ is known) and $Q=Q^T>0$. $V$ is the Lyapunov candidate function and the constants $Γ$ and $γ_r$ are positive adaptation gains.

$$ \dot{V} = \dot{e}^TPe+e^TP\dot{e}+|b|(2\tilde{K}Γ^{-1}\dot{\tilde{K}}^T+2γ_r^{-1}\tilde{k}_r\dot{\tilde{k}}_r) $$

Now by substituting the equation for $\dot{e}$ I have derived the following result:

$$ \dot{V} = -e^TQe+2e^TPB(-\tilde{k}_rr-\tilde{K}x)+|b|(2\tilde{K}Γ^{-1}\dot{\tilde{K}}^T+2γ_r^{-1}\tilde{k}_r\dot{\tilde{k}}_r) $$

The term $2e^TPB$ can be written $2e^T\bar{P}b$ where $\bar{P}=[p_{12} \ \ p_{22}]^T$ and since the sign of $b$ is known, $b = |b|sgn(b)$. Taking these into consideration I have reached the final form of $\dot{V}$ which is :

$$ \dot{V} = -e^TQe+2|b|\tilde{K}(-xe^T\bar{P}sgn(b)+Γ^{-1}\dot{\hat{K}}^T)+2|b|\tilde{k}_r(-re^T\bar{P}sgn(b)+γ_r^{-1}\dot{\hat{k}}_r) $$

Defining the update laws to be:

$$ \dot{\hat{K}}^T=Γxe^T\bar{P}sgn(b) $$

$$ \dot{\hat{k}}_r = γ_rre^T\bar{P}sgn(b) $$

we are left with $\dot{V} = -e^TQe \le 0$. I am writing this more for validating purposes since I am not so sure if I computed the derivatives of the transposed matrices together with the normal matrices correctly (I know it is time-consuming but anyone who is willing would really help) and also is there any other good option regarding the Lyapunov candidate function which I could consider ?

Comment: Can you improve your notation/explanation? Suddenly there are time depended gains and I don't see the sudden dependency of $x$ in the error dynamics: $e = x-x_m$, $\dot{e} = \dot{x}-\dot{x}_m = Ax +Bu - A_m x_m - B_r r = Ax - BK x + Bk_r r - A_m x_m - B_r r = A_m x + Bk_r r - A_m x_m - B_r r = A_m e + (Bk_r - B_r) r$. How do you end up with $K(t)x$ and the minus sign in front of $Bk_r$?

Comment: Think I fixed it now. Error term should be $e=x_m-x$, the controller $u=K(t)x+k_r(t)r$ and the matching condition $A+BK=A_m$. The gains change over time since the controller adapts to follow the desired reference.

Comment: Where did you get that candidate from? Is there some reference to this problem or something?

Comment: You are right, I didn't mention it. The book "Model Reference Adaptive Control, A Primer" by Nguyes chapter 5.4.